# Converting error with RDD operation in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and I ran into the error while doing some practice.

I tried to convert RDD into DataFrame and following is my code.

```
package com.sclee.examples

import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.IntType
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType};


object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("examples").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

    val personRDD = sc.makeRDD(Seq(Person("A",10),Person("B",20)))
    val df = personRDD.map({
      case Row(val1: String, val2: Long) => Person(val1,val2)
    }).toDS()

//    val ds = personRDD.toDS()
  }
}
```

I followed the instructions in Spark documentation and also referenced some blogs showing me how to convert rdd into dataframe but the I got the error below.

```
Error:(20, 27) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val df = personRDD.map({
```

Although I tried to fix the problem by myself but failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
object SparkTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // use the SparkSession of Spark 2
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // this your RDD - just a sample how to create an RDD
    val personRDD: RDD[Person] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Person("A",10),Person("B",20)))

   // the sparksession has a method to convert to an Dataset
   val ds = spark.createDataset(personRDD)
   println(ds.count())
  }
}
```

I made the following changes:

- use `SparkSession` instead of `SparkContext` and `SqlContext`
- move `Person` class out of the App (I'm not sure why I had to do
  this)
- use `createDataset` for conversion

However, I guess it's pretty uncommon to do this conversion and you probably want to read your input directly into an `Dataset` using the [`read`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@read:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) method